# ¿Como sincronizar las bases de datos de mysql en varios ordenadores?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

En mi caso tengo un servidor principal con 3 bases de datos: bdA, bdB, bdC. Después tengo 3 servidores secundarios: sA, sB, sC.
El servidor sA solo tiene la bdA y solo debe sincronizarse con esta. Los cambios del sA deben verse reflejados en la bdA del servidor principal de igual forma que los cambios realizados en la bdA del servidor principal deben reflejarse en el sA. Del mismo modo el sB solo debe sincronizarse con la base de datos bdB y el sC solo debe sincronizarse con la base de datos bdC.
Es posible utilizar la replicación circular del mysql para este fin? Si no es así hay alguna otra forma de lograr este objetivo?
Gracias

Comment: Hola Joel, lo que tu necesitas es montar un cluster de mysql. He visto este enlace donde lo explican de una manera muy sencilla, espero que te sirva: https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/mysql-cluster/

Comment: Disculpa, pero no veo replicación en lo qu tu describes, solamente 3 servidores con un servidor BD cada uno. Replicación con mysql es posible y funciona bien, pero no logro en ver donde intentas implementarlo entre bdA, bdB y bdC. Podrias proveer un diagrama de despliegue o algo parecido?

Comment: Hola Stefan, el servidor principal tiene las tres bases de datos, el sA solo tiene la bdA y la comunicación entre el servidor principal y el sA solo debería ser para la bdA. Del mismo modo el servidor principal solo debería sincronizar la bdB con el sB. Lo mismo con el sC que solo debería recibir la bdC. No hay comunicación entre los servidores sA, sB y sC